# Getting the organization a project belongs to in GCP using go sdk

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sdk

I am listing my projects as follows:

```golang
listProjectsResponse, err := projectsListCall.Do()
```

Where a [`projectsListCall`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1?tab=doc#ProjectsListCall) is a type provided by the `cloudresourcemanager` and its [`v1beta1`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1?tab=doc) API.

I couldn't find a way though to be able to retrieve a the [`Organization`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1?tab=doc#Organization) a project belongs to. Is this feasible using the above api/sdk?

I am able to access the `Parent` field of a `Project` which is of type `*cloudresourcemanager.ResourceId`, however I cannot find a way to traverse up the tree until I reach the `Organization`.

What is more, I think it would be easier to find a way to say:

- Given this `Organization`, list me all its projects.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sadly I don't speak go ... but from a REST API perspective,  Given a projectId, I can get the ancestry using https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getAncestry ... which returns an array which contains a resourceId of type organization which gives me the organization id of the project ... which I can then use to get the details of the organization using https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go SDK allows to retrieve that information through the methods ["ProjectGetAncestryCall"](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1?tab=doc#ProjectsGetAncestryCall) and ["OrganizationsGetCall"](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1?tab=doc#OrganizationsGetCall). If you dig a bit in the documentation you'll see that the methods call the API endpoints mentioned by Kolban in his comment.

Moreover, whenever a doubt of this kind arises you might try searching the corresponding API endpoint in Google's documentation and then search for it in the Go SDK documentation because generally the endpoint is mentioned there.